# Reading an old (damaged) CD-R

Tags: data-recovery, data-cd

I am trying to recover data from an old CD that was in storage.
However, when I try to mount it:

```
sudo mount -t hfs /dev/cdrom /mnt
```

I get the message

```
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

Is there any way to recover data off the CD?  My guess is that the CD-ROM drive has to be able to read the disk at some kind of low level before allowing `dd` to see it.  As a result of that not working, `dd` just generates errors.  Are there any tools  to  solve this?

So far I have tried:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/cdrom of=badcd3.iso bs=2048 conv=noerror,notrunc iflag=nonblock
```

as described in: http://hyperlogos.org/page/Recovering-damaged-CDs-or-DVDs-Linux

As you can see in the pic... the dye is coming away from the edges.  I was hoping to be able to get the stuff in the centre...

Interestingly, it was mounting earlier on my MacBook, but now it just comes up as a blank CD.

If DD doesn't work, is there any way within Unix or Linux to go any further?

[image: bad CD]

Comment: This isn't a Unix question but rather a general storage medium/hardware question. In any event, it's there for all to see. That CD-R is physically damaged to the point that it can't be read anymore so unless you've got the data elsewhere, there's nothing that can be done.

Comment: @NasirRiley I am asking from a Unix / Linux perspective.   If there is nothing more that can be done, then that could be the answer to my question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about hardware.

Comment: Since this hyperlogos site does not mention `readcd`, it seems that the author is not really experienced with reading damaged CDs.

Comment: If anyone here can help it'll be @schily

Comment: @xirt It has nothing to do with Unix or the operating system that's being used. It's a hardware issue and not a software/OS issue.

Comment: Did you try dvdisaster?

Comment: I have been told that dvdisaster is a software that allows to add more forward error correction before the disk is written. In any case, it will never help with disks that are not recognised by the drive.

Answer (score 3):

If a CD is defective, the usual UNIX tools do not help.

As long as you get the no medium found message, you cannot do anything.

You first need to check whether this is a blank CD-R medium and your drive is only a CD-ROM drive that does not understand unwritten CD-R media.

If this is a CD writer, then it should be able to detect the medium and in such a case, `cdrecord -v -minfo` prints information about the actual media status. If the CD was written, then here is more help:

If there is no dust and no scratches on the disk, the only way is to find a better drive that accepts the medium, ot at least to reload the medium repeatedly until the drive likes the medium.

Note that in order to recognise a CD, the drive needs to read the `TOC`.

The `TOC` it at the inner circle of the medium and equipped with few error recovery data, but repeated several times. If there is a larger gap as a result of a larger space in the disk, where nothing can be read, then there is few hope to be able to read the `TOC`.

Once you nanage to managed to make the drive to recognise the medium, you should use `readcd` to recover from the rest of the problems.

`readcd` is in `cdrtools` for final releases and in the `schilytools` for frequent snapshots. It includes the recovery features from `sdd`  and in addition even more (Reed Solomon recovery code that may be better than what you have in the firmware of the drive).

I recommend to start with getting the medium recognised by the drive...

Here is the `readcd` man page: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/readcd.1.html

Comment: I am using another machine with a different CD-ROM drive (Samsung again) but this time the drive reads the CD with DD.  Will try with the other tools you suggest but might take a while.  DD was running for over two days straight and seemed to be looping over 0 byte reads.  Will update when I have final info.

Answer (score 1):

There is another variant of `dd`, called `gddrescue`.
This is a better choice for this job, because it enhances the original `dd` command to handle read errors.
But unfortunately I assume that, if your system doesn't recognize the CD, it can't be rescued.

Comment: Even on non optical media, I would prefer `sdd` over your `gddrescue`, but on optical median, you need software that is able to access the data via low level `SCSI`-commands.

Comment: I have successfully recoverd corrupted CDs with `gddrescue`. I don't know about `sdd` and it seems that it is not in debian repo. Where can I find it?

Comment: Tools like dd cannot do much for problematic CDs, so when it did help you, there was not much damage on that optical medium. `sdd -noerror` uses techniques that have been developped and verified with hundreds of customer disks in the mid 1980s already. Use a lrger `try=` value for better results. The code is in the schilytools. `readcd` includes the recovery procedure from `sdd` but it works at `SCSI` level and thus can do more for CDs.

Answer (score 0):

> My guess is that the CD-ROM drive has to be able to read the disk at some kind of low level before allowing dd to see it.

Why would you guess that? `dd` and `mount` report what the kernel says. The kernel says “no medium found”. This means that as far as the software is concerned, the CD drive is empty.

There is no way to recover any data using software because the hardware reports that the CD is not present or blank. It may be possible to recover data using specialized, expensive hardware — or maybe even by some cheap “homebrew” technique or simply by using a CD reader with more sensitive equipemtn — but this is off-topic for this site, and I wouldn't set your hopes very high: CDs don't age well.

Answer (score 0):

Some hardware is better at reading balky discs. Sometimes it's not the drive's hardware, but its *firmware*:

> Blank CD-R disks have a code that your CD writer reads to find the best writing strategy. If this isn't in the CD-writer's inbuilt software (its "firmware"), the default may be a poor compromise. Vane-Tempest says that some "less scrupulous" Far East companies have been using other people's codes, with deficient results. However, there is a way around this which is to find out which brands suit your writer and ensure the firmware is up to date.
>     -- [The Myth Of 
>   The 100-Year CD-Rom](http://www.rense.com/general52/themythofthe100year.htm)

So step #1 is to find out if there's any newer firmware for your optical drive.

Failing that, try every CD drive you can find, especially older *Plextor* drives.  If one works, do as [*Winnie Tigger* advised](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450781/165517) and make an image using `gddrescue`.